# Deploying ear with jenkins executing shell script

Tags: shell, jenkins, deployment, weblogic, ear

I'm trying to deploy a .ear file to my test environment using Jenkins.

The web application is running on Bea Weblogic 9.2, so i though the easiest way to do this is just execute the following script in the post build steps (add post buils steps--->execute shell):

```
java weblogic.Deployer -adminurl t3://22.33.44.55:8001 -username myUserName -password myPassword -deploy -name earfilename -targets AdminServer -source C:\apps\sample.ear
```

Assuming that this will work, i'm sure you will agree with me that this does not make sense bacause the -source is pointing at my local ear. I want instead to deploy the ear file that was just builded from jenkins (which is the result of the SVN commit).

So my final question is: is there any environment variable i can put in my script to get the -source (path to the ear just builded) and -name (the name of the artifact changes with each version)?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

source parameter doesnt need to have the filename with it, it should be C:\apps\ and put name as the application name. you can also add a one liner command to remove the already existing apps before the new build is created so that apps folder only has one file. If the ear file resides in a remote server use -remote option with the command.

e.g

java -cp $CLASSPATH weblogic.Deployer -adminurl ADMIN_URL:PORT -username weblogic -password weblogic1! -distribute app.war -name appname -targets AdminServer -debug
-usenonexclusivelock

you can also check the name of ear file with find command, store it in a variable and use that variable in the command.